# PHP - FPM - Nginx - serving PHP files

Tags: php, nginx, macos

I have PHP installed locally on a macOS Catalina 10.15.3 system;

```
php -i
phpinfo()
PHP Version => 7.3.11
```

I have Nginx up and running serving static files:
[image]
What's the easiest method to make Nginx and PHP serve script files? I know there are numerous articles out there, but all vary one way or another and not all are suitable for my needs. I've taken  a look at https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.install.php but can't find the `php.ini` I'm using for the webserver? Since I can't as yet serve PHP files I can't simply place a file on the root and use: `phpinfo()`

```
php -i | grep "Configuration File"
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc
Loaded Configuration File => (none)
```

More info on local setup;

```
server {
        listen       8080;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm index.php;
        }
```

So attempting to install `PHP-FPM` and immediately the fun and games (online reference) begin with;

```
$ brew tap homebrew/dupes
$ brew tap homebrew/php
$ brew install --without-apache --with-fpm php71
```

```
Error: homebrew/dupes was deprecated. This tap is now empty as all its formulae were migrated.
Error: homebrew/php was deprecated. This tap is now empty as all its formulae were migrated.
Error: invalid option: --without-apache
```

If you could offer some clues or give me a nudge in the right direction that'd be great.

Comment: The "easiest" if you just want to do some testing would be to not use nginx, but the integrated webserver: `cd path/to/phpfiles/; php -S localhost:8000`

Comment: Thanks. I would really like to setup Nginx though.

Comment: PHP-FPM is the easiest option. Please write which Linux distro you are using.

Comment: MacOS Catalina 10.15.3 - thanks